# jquery How to memory effect: show two, then hide and repeat

Tags: jquery, memory, hide, show

hello all how can I achieve a memory effect with my code? With memory effect I mean: you can click two images to show() them. On the third click the showing images hide() and the next two images can be clicked on to shown.

*edit: the third click should show the first image of the second try.*

In my example this works only once, because I don't know where to return or reset the amountofclicks.

Hope you can help me out?

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/P99Xu/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">

<div class="coverup">

     <div class="hoverdiv">
     </div>

     <div class="image">
     </div>


</div>

    <div class="coverup">

     <div class="hoverdiv">
     </div>

     <div class="image">
     </div>


</div>

    <div class="coverup">

     <div class="hoverdiv">
     </div>

     <div class="image">
     </div>


</div>

    <div class="coverup">

     <div class="hoverdiv">
     </div>

     <div class="image">
     </div>


</div>

    <div class="coverup">

     <div class="hoverdiv">
     </div>

     <div class="image">
     </div>


</div>

    <div class="coverup">

     <div class="hoverdiv">
     </div>

     <div class="image">
     </div>

</div>

    <div class="coverup">

     <div class="hoverdiv">
     </div>

     <div class="image">
     </div>


</div>

    <div class="coverup">

     <div class="hoverdiv">
     </div>

     <div class="image">
     </div>


</div>
```

**JS**

```
var amountofclicks = 0;
$('.coverup').hover(

function() {
    $(this).find('.hoverdiv').fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.hoverdiv').fadeOut('fast');
});

$('.coverup').bind("click", function(event) {

    if (amountofclicks < 2) {
        $(this).find('.image').show();
        amountofclicks++;
        $(this).unbind('click');
        $('.hoverdiv').hide();
    } else {
        $('.image').hide();
        return;
    }

});
```

Comment: Try to change `if(amountofclick < 2){...}` to `if(amountofclick % 2){...}`. Then you wouldn't need to reset the counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reset `amountofclicks`. jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P99Xu/4/

Also, no need to unbind the click.

```
$('.coverup').bind("click", function(event) {

    if (amountofclicks < 2) {
        $(this).find('.image').show();
        amountofclicks++;
        $('.hoverdiv').hide();
    } else {
        $('.image').hide();
        $(this).find('.image').show();
        amountofclicks = 1;
        return;
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is it also possible that the third click opens/shows, because now the third click does nothing (my bad though)

Comment: Updated my answer and jsFiddle, is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Set `amountofclicks = 0` when it reaches 2 and `else part` is executed. You do not need to `unbind` the click event.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P99Xu/2/)**

```
$('.coverup').bind("click", function(event) {

    if (amountofclicks < 2) {
        $(this).find('.image').show();
        amountofclicks++;
       // $(this).unbind('click');
        $('.hoverdiv').hide();
    } else {
        $('.image').hide();
        amountofclicks = 0;
        return;
    }

});​
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The third click should also be able to open/show the image my bad, how can i accomplish this?